# jQuery .draggable() either doesn't drag or drags too many cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm making a web app for poker cards. The idea is you drag cards from a deck to a hand/board and it ranks it for you. The functionality of the site works; I just can't get the cards to be able to drag from the deck to the board.

1. Draggable doesn't work on the card, and the text of the card is highlighted instead.
2. Draggable does work, but it drags more cards than I want it to. For example, I'll try to drag the 3 of diamonds and for some reason it grabs all the 3s and some of the 4s.

How can I get dragging a single card working correctly?

```css
.card {
  height: 9.2em;
  width: 6.61em;
  padding-left: .2em;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin:.2em;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="deck">
    {% for card in deck %}
        <div class="drag">
            <div id="{{card.rank}}{{card.suit}}" class="card rank{{ card.rank }}{{ card.suit }}">
                {{ card.rank }} <br/> &{{ card.suit_verbose }};
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".drag").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: here's the Jinja html:

```
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
    <h1 class="container text-center">
        two pair
    </h1>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="canvas">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="board">          
                <div class="row col-md-1">
                    <span class="card empty"/>
                </div>            
                <div class="row col-md-1">
                    <span class="card empty"/>
                </div>

                ...

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems right... Can you post the jinja generated html? (use ctrl+u in browser)

Comment: I threw in an edit with it.

Comment: Need a demo that replicates this if you want help. hard to troubleshoot a UI we can't see

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/timredd13/csdxdhrt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, but it looks like you simply forgot to add jQuery UI to your scripts. I added jQuery UI to your fiddle and it works (checked on Chrome and FF). Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/wx5oz45g/1/ . Only other change was adding `cursor: pointer` in CSS to class `.drag` so I could see better what should be responsive.